# tweepy error while getting tweets

Tags: tweets, tweepy

I'm collecting a large number of tweets via tweepy,
but after a while, it stops with the following message:

```
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 185, in _call
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 168, in execute
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'Sorry, that page does not exist', 'code': 34}]
```

I'm only collecting the replies to already-existing tweets,

so I'm guessing it is the case where the replier misspelled the author of the original tweet..

Is there a workaround to ignore this and proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself.
It was ridiculously simple..
You can just try/except and pass on the error.

```
try:
        # do something                                    
except tweepy.error.TweepError:
        pass
```

Comment: Did you confirm it was because the username was spelled wrong?